# Joomla 2.5 JFactory query `where` clause does not work. What is wrong?

Tags: php, joomla

I have been writing a Joomla 2.5 module, in `helper.php`, I wrote the following code:

```
public static function getHello( $params )
{
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $clause = 'title like \'.$params\'';
    $query
        ->select(array('id','alias','extension'))
        ->from('#__categories')
        ->where($clause);

    // Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
    $db->setQuery($query);

    // Load the results as a list of stdClass objects.
    $results = $db->loadAssocList();

    return $results;
}
```

However, when I retrieve the query results, I always get an empty result. I think I was wrong in writing the syntax on the `$clause` variable, but I do not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: What's inside $params? Can you show var_dump($params);? And what title are you searching in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$clause` variable

```
$clause = 'title like \'.$params\'';
```

contains the string

```
title like '.$params'
```

Obviously, you don't have a category with that name.

Some tipps:

1. **Avoid escaping of quotes.**
   If you had used double quotes for the string, you might have seen the problem yourself:

   ```
   $clause = "title like '.$params'";
   ```

   The correct syntax is

   ```
   $clause = "title like '" . $params . "'";
   ```
2. **Always escape strings before submitting them to the database.** Otherwise you're open to SQL attacks.

   ```
   $clause = "title like '" . $db->escape($params) . "'";
   ```
3. **Use the API.** The database object provides a method to properly escape *and* quote strings.

   ```
   $clause = "title like " . $db->quote($params);
   ```
4. **Use uppercase for SQL keywords.** That increases readability of SQL strings significantly.

   ```
   $clause = "title LIKE " . $db->quote($params);
   ```

Since you use `LIKE`, I assume you're looking for *partial* titles. In that case ensure that `$params` is surrounded with `%`, which is the SQL wildcard character.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
$clause = 'title like \'.$params\'';
```

to

```
$clause = 'title like "'.$params.'"';
```

Comment: here is a syntax error at $clause = 'title like "'.$params'"'; you missed one "." on right end $clause = 'title like "'.$params.'"';

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$clause = "title like '".$db->escape($params)."'";
```

or

```
$clause = 'title like "'.$db->escape($params).'"';
```

Comment: what is the content of $params its contains special characters or qts try $db->escape($params) .

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
$clause = "title like {$db->quote($params)}";
```

or

```
$clause = "title like {$params}";
```

it's much easier for reading.